# Accessing another user' status via outlook interop dll

Tags: c#, outlook

If I open someone else's calendar in outlook, I can see if they have book out time for meetings. They are set to busy, tentative, etc.
Is it possible to get this information via the outlook interop dll? Haven't had any success googling a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using this bit of code;

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
NameSpace ns = outlookApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
ns.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, true);
AddressEntries addressBook = ns.GetGlobalAddressList().AddressEntries;
AddressEntry testSearch = addressBook["LastName, FirstName"];
Console.WriteLine("FreeBusy: {0}", testSearch.GetFreeBusy(DateTime.Now, 30, true));
```

Still have to parse the GetFreeBusy string into something useful, but there's nothing simpler as far as I can find. Not sure if the NameSpace logon is necessary (used it in another piece of code) but it's not slowing things down or causing any issues...

Answer (score 1):

Use Recipient.FreeBusy or AddressEntry.GetFreeBusy.